# velodyne_driver: will you provide a model for the VLP-16?

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver, vlp-16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently the velodyne_driver package supports only the HDL-32 and 64. Will you provide a model for the VLP-16 soon?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202824/velodyne_driver:-will-you-provide-a-model-for-the-vlp-16?/) by [simonan-ecn](https://answers.ros.org/users/21598/simonan-ecn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to, but I don't have access to that device, so I will need significant help from someone who does.

There is already a patch at the driver level, submitted by Brice Rebsamen. But, it does not include the additional point cloud conversions that are apparently needed.

See: https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/pull/38

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-11-12**:
The current source master now supports the VLP-16. An Indigo release is planned.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-07-06**:
The VLP-16 support was contributed by Patrick Hussey, with help from several others. It will be released soon, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't speak for @joq, but it is unlikely Clearpath will contribute/test unless we start working with the VLP-16.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1